# return another String if url page is blank

Tags: java

How would I return a default String if Im trying to read a blank webpage?

```
private void setVersion(String input) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(input);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

            String getInfo;
            while ((getInfo = in.readLine()) != null) {
                Console("[setVersion Length]" + getInfo.length());
                dModVersionList.addElement(getInfo);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            dModVersionList.addElement("Unknown");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I want to addElement even when the while loop return null, I can already handle it if the page no longer exists

Comment: What is a blank web page to you, is a page with hidden text blank?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this can work:

```
        String getInfo;
        // set initially to false
        boolean found = false;
        while ((getInfo = in.readLine()) != null) {
            found = true; // found some data; set to true
            Console("[setVersion Length]" + getInfo.length());
            dModVersionList.addElement(getInfo);
        }
        // still false; add your specific element
        if (!found)
            dModVersionList.addElement("no data");
```

Comment: awesome thanks this one may be proving to work ... so far :) thanks for the help

Comment: Glad to know. Can you mark this answer as accepted now to help future visitors on this page.

Answer (score 1):

Just a try.

```
        while (true) {
            Console("[setVersion Length]" + getInfo.length());
            getInfo = in.readLine();
            if(getInfo.equals("exit")
               break;
            dModVersionList.addElement(getInfo);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `while` loop returns `null`, means that it wont enter your `loop`, so after your loop you can do `null` check for `getInfo` and then set any `String` you want,you can do something like

```
                //local variable should be initialised.
                String getInfo = null;
                while ((getInfo = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    Console("[setVersion Length]" + getInfo.length());
                    dModVersionList.addElement(getInfo);
                }
                if(getInfo == null){
                   dModVersionList.addElement("Web page returns empty");
                }
```

Comment: `getInfo`'s initial value is of course null, but I think it's better coding practice to specifically initialize it to null. So I would advise against this practice. Also see [my post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026240/return-another-string-if-url-page-is-blank/19026348#19026348)

Comment: @tmn29a only `instance` variables will be assigned `default`, for String it would be `null` , and local variable without `initialising`, the code wont get compiled. So more than `good practice`, it wont even allow you to run without initialising.